# How do you create multiple test files in jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs

Having this node.js app which is going to be quite huge.
First I created a file named

```
user.account.test.js
```

In that I begun putting all the possible tests (positive and negative tests) for the usuale flow: signup, singin, activation, restore password etc.

At the end I have this file that is over 600 rows. Now, Im going to create a lot of more tests. And having everything in the same file sounds silly to me.

I could not really find resources that explain how to split the test in severals test files.
Im having a nightmare when I created a new test file where to put other tests. I mostly got timeout issues.
And a lot of things look strange. For example:

In the  user.account.test.js I had this line:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_TEST_URI);
});
```

In the second test file, named user.step2.test.js, I was unsure if I had to also put the same function.
At the end I did it, and incredibly that file did not know anything about "process.env.MONGODB_TEST_URI".

What is the best practice when you want to split tests into multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solution seems to be adding the flag  --runInBand. Then they will run sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

For me each routes I write one test file.
For example:

[image]

Each test file have sth like this:

```
import request from 'supertest'
import {app} from '../../app'

it('create new user', async() => {
  return request(app).post('/api/users')
  .send({account: "123", password:"123"})
  .expect(201)
})
```

and I create a test setup file:

[image]

```
beforeAll(async () => {
 // init your database connection here
})

beforeEach(() => {
  // delete all data in your database
})

afterAll(async() => {
 //close your db connection 
})
```

and in package.json:

```
 "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./src/test/setup.ts"
    ]
  },
```